# Can I list tabs in firefox by their memory and cpu usages and find the one with most usages?

Tags: firefox

When opening multiple tabs for different webpages in Firefox, is it possible to find out which tab uses most memory? Or to list the tabs by their memory usage? Similarly for CPU usage per tab?

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04. But I don't think you can identify tabs from OS processes, because [they are said to not match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484132).

> Therefore, the total number of processes are controlled by the configuration, and is not directly related to the number of tabs in use. You can check the configuration for your system under Options > General > Performance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type "about:memory" in the address bar and press Enter, you should get some info about RAM usage, per tab, total, etc...

Comment: Thanks. How about CPU usage?

Comment: about:performance, I think.